# Why texture appears like this after smear applied?

Tags: shaders, texture-painting

I have an intricate sweet cookie made of chunked flavoured rise. I've used meatballs and a particle system as per other thread explained, I also created a seamless texture and applied to it, the thing is that since is very intricate and merged with another similar object then it displays the texture uneven, and looks bad.

I've used the smear tool to drag the sharp corners and make it look better, but on the final render it keeps appearing as a cuted edge. Any way to fix this?

thanks in advance:

The Smeared applied very well as you can see
[image: image with texture applied well]

The rendered version, can you see the jittered and badly gutted edges?
[image: rendered version]

Answer (score 1):

You can set your seamless texture image to "box" instead of "flat" ad play with the blend value to get something convincing.

Flat:
[image]
Box:
[image]